# Get Response Value and Set in Variables Postman

Tags: postman

I'm making `postman` call and it responds with different `headers` e.g. `access-token`, `client`, `uid` etc I want to retrieve their values and save in `environment variables` so that I don't have to set `access-token` every time. Can anyone guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> it responds with different headers

```
var access-token = postman.getResponseHeader("access-token");
var uid = postman.getResponseHeader("uid");

pm.environment.set("access-token", access-token);
pm.environment.set("uid ", uid);
```

**OR** shorter way

```
pm.environment.set("access-token", postman.getResponseHeader("access-token"));
pm.environment.set("uid ", postman.getResponseHeader("uid"));
```

> if it responds access-token, client, uid in response body then below is the way to get and set them -

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var uid = jsonData.uid;
var access-token = jsonData.access-token;

pm.environment.set("access-token", access-token);
pm.environment.set("uid ", uid);
```

**OR** shorter way -

```
pm.environment.set("access-token", jsonData.access-token);
pm.environment.set("uid ", jsonData.uid);
```

note- this will only work if response body is only one json object, in other cases path will change to access the required values.

FYI - You might wondering why there is [pm and postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3648)